# How to stall execution of function line by line?

Tags: python, testing

I'm having a hard time summerizing the question so I'll describe what I'm trying to do:

I'm writing a test solution for a certain product, lets say a microwave. The purpose is to measure all sorts of resources, while the microwave is being used. For that purpose I wrote a context manager called `measure()`.

Using the microwave API I wrote a function that simulates a basic use case of the microwave, and decorated it with a function that does all of the measuring:

```
def test_function(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with measure():
            fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@test_function
def prepare_food():
    microwave = Microwave()
    microwave.open_door()
    microwave.insert_food()
    microwave.close_door()
    microwave.turn_on(seconds = 60)

prepare_food()
```

Of course the microwave is only one example and I have a lot of this "microwaves".

After a few days of testing and measuring my team decided they want to measure each action separately, meaning my test function will now look like this:

```
def test_prepare_food():
    microwave = Microwave()
    actions = {
            microwave.open_door : [],
            microwave.insert_food : [],
            microwave.close_door() : [],
            microwave.turn_on : [60]
            }
    for (action, args) in actions.items():
            with measure():
                action(*args)
```

The problem with the new `test_prepare_food` is that now for each `prepare_food` function, I need to add  another `test_*` function (and I have a lot).

I'm looking for an elegant way of keeping my `prepare_food` function the same, and wrap it with another function so I'll still get the same functionality as in `test_prepare_food`.

**Edit:**
The goal is for a solution which will not be dependent on a the implementation of `prepare_food()`, so that a change in `prepare_food()` would not require additional changes. Also, the solution should not affect methods which are not in use by `prepare_food`.

In other words, I'd like to be able to "step into" `prepare_food` and be able to execute code before and after each line. That resembles to what is done while debugging, but I couldn't find any thing similar.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to get this out of the way early on: You're not just looking to measure *execution time* for each line, correct? (Because that would be a job for a profiler). You also need to keep track of some other resources that need custom code to be measured?

Comment: @LukasGraf - that's right, I'm measuring other resources, stuff like the heat the microwave produces, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could decorate each instance method of the Microwave class with the `measure` method. This can be accomplished with a class decorator on the Microwave class. For this example, I'll just modify the Microwave class via a method. The methods that accomplish the work are `wrap` and `wrap_method`.

```
import inspect

class measure(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Enter measure."
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print "Exit measure."

class Microwave(object):
    def f(self, x):
        print "f: %s" % x
    def g(self, x):
        print "g: %s" % x

def wrap_method(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with measure():
            method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def wrap(cls):
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(cls, name, wrap_method(method))

wrap(Microwave)
m = Microwave()
m.f(1)
m.g(2)
```

Output is:

```
Enter measure.
f: 1
Exit measure.
Enter measure.
g: 2
Exit measure.
```

Comment: +1 for using `inspect.getmembers` but it's not exactly what I'm looking for- 1) it depends on the implementation of `prepare_food`; 2) it will change all of `Microwave`'s methods- including those that are not used directly by me. I edited the question to mention this requirements.